# 301 redirect from old URL structur to new

Tags: redirect

I recently updated the permalink structure of a website from `/%postname%/` to `/%category%/%postname%/` this is obviously causing 404 errors. Instead of writing 301 redirects for each post is there any way to do this in a more automated fashion, within WordPress? I essentially want to programmatically 301 redirect the URIs from the old permalink structure to the new one.

Comment: Not sure what is actually the question. If there are plugins that let you redirect URLs then all you have to do is find away to automatically populate them.

Comment: Also not sure what you asking. I cannot replicate your problem.

Comment: I updated the permanent structure to include the category. Now the old URLs 404. Is there a way to programmatically 301 redirect the old permalink structure to the new one?

Comment: I updated the question to make it a little more clear if it wasn't before @MarkKaplun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a catch on 404 in wordpress with filter 404_template

Or you can use redirection plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/screenshots/ with Regex.

Can you follow the link in this Question: [Catch 404 after changing permalink structure from /%postname%/ to /%category%/%postname%/](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94644/catch-404-after-changing-permalink-structure-from-postname-to-category-p)

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Redirect a "/%postname%/" permalink structure to the their new URL.
 * 
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/136306/1685
 */
function wpse_136306_redirect() {
    global $wp;

    // Check that we've hit a 404 for a non-empty permalink without slashes
    if ( is_404() && strlen( $wp->request ) && strpos( $wp->request, '/' ) === false ) {
        // Attempt to find a post that matches the request.
        $posts = get_posts(
            array(
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'name' => $wp->request,
            )
        );

        if ( $posts && $url = get_permalink( $posts[0]->ID ) ) {
            // All good, let's redirect to the new URL.
            wp_redirect( $url, 301 );
            exit;
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_136306_redirect', 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any advantages or disadvantages using this method versus the one in the above answer? I just want to make sure i'm implementing this in the best way possible @thedeadmedic

Comment: Not really, though I prefer my solution, naturally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with a Wordpress plugin , you can use the [WP redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/).

Regular expressions are your friends
https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/

In the `Source URL`, set `.*`

In `Target URL`, set `/category/$1` . The tricky part is your `category` is a variable.