# Redirect /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%

Tags: permalinks, redirect, wp-redirect

Need to redirect to new structure   /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/**%category%**/%postname%

Saw code that helped before but can't seem to find it. Updated theme and lost the code that went into functions.php. Backup best practices are important!

**UPDATE:** Found the code again! It was first posted @ [Catch 404 after changing permalink structure from /%postname%/ to /%category%/%postname%/](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94644/catch-404-after-changing-permalink-structure-from-postname-to-category-p)

```
add_filter( '404_template', 't5_redirect_to_category' );

function t5_redirect_to_category( $template )
{
    if ( ! is_404() )
        return $template;

    global $wp_rewrite, $wp_query;

    // change 'yourpermalink' to your new permalink structure
    // my new structure is '/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%category%/%postname%'
    if ( 'yourpermalink' !== $wp_rewrite->permalink_structure )
        return $template;

    if ( ! $post = get_page_by_path( $wp_query->query['category_name'], OBJECT, 'post' ) )
        return $template;

    $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );

    wp_redirect( $permalink, 301 );
    exit;
}
```

Stick this code in functions.php using the theme editor. The code can redirect all new permalink configurations that are currently returning as a 404 due to changes.

**Remember to save this code because every time you update the theme it will be removed and you will need to add it to functions.php again.**

This literally saved me. Thanks https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/fuxia!

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell you how I handle things like this.

I swear by [redirections](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) which is a plugin that handles this sort of thing. It can be set to detect permalink changes and redirect old to new. Then you just go into perma-link and restructure as you wish. As someone who tends to figure out better ways to do things as he works, this is so much help for me.